# DIV redimensionar após ser clicada

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, div

**olá

tenho uma pagina com varias DIV.  que são varias Notícias diferentes.

essas DIV tão num tamanho de 300px por 250px,

 gostaria de saber como faço para ao clicar em alguma dessas div ela redimencionar 
na tela e ficar maior ,fazendo com que apareça todo o conteúdo que ta dentro dela
 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mas a div aumentada vai ficar por cima das outras, vai empurrar as outras, como é?

Comment: Bom tb colocar o HTML do que já fez porque dependendo de como está fazendo por influenciar no resultado.

Comment: @Sam  na verdade quando essa DIV abrir não vai aparecer as outras.

Comment: Posta o código na pergunta.

Comment: Então vc quer que ao clicar abra um popup com a noticia? Tipo clica na div e abre uma "janela" por cima da pagina mostrando apenas a noticia clicada?

Comment: Modal Boostrap ficaria bom no seu caso

Comment: @hugocsl  e isso  ai

Answer (score 1):

Veja se o código abaixo te ajuda.

Ele não esta utilizando [`jQuery`](https://jquery.com/), [`bootstrap`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/) que ferramentas que vale apena você dar uma olhada

```js
function onClick(){
    var self=this, // ; elemento clicada
        isOpen = self.classList.contains('open');

    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('noticia'))
       .forEach(function(el,idx){
            if( isOpen )
            {
                el.className='noticia'; // ; mostra a list noticia
            }
            else if( self != el )
            {
             el.className += ' close'; // ; esconde a lista
            }
            else
            {
             el.className += ' open'; // ; espande a noticia clicada
            }
       });
    }

/// Adicionar evento de onClick no elementos com a class noticia
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('noticia')).forEach(function(el,idx){
    el.onclick = onClick;
});
```

```css
.noticias-container{
    text-align:center;
}
.noticias-container .noticia{
    display: inline-block;
    border:1px solid red;
    width: calc( 32.222% - 5px ); /* Coloquei tamanho flexivel para exibir aqui */
    margin: 3px 3px;
    height: 250px;
}
.noticias-container .noticia.close{
    display:none;
}

.noticias-container .noticia.open{
    width: 600px;
    height: 550px;
}
```

```html
<div class='noticias-container'>
  <div class='noticia'>ELEMENTO 1</div>
  <div class='noticia'>ELEMENTO 2</div>
  <div class='noticia'>ELEMENTO 3</div>
  <div class='noticia'>ELEMENTO 4</div>
  <div class='noticia'>ELEMENTO 5</div>
  <div class='noticia'>ELEMENTO 6</div>
</div>
```